# Pretty print request object in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, ajax

Is there a way to pretty print a request object in Node?
The default console.log is not very informative.

Comment: `The default console.log is not very informative.` is not a helpful description of what information is missing, or what information you expect that should be shown.  (And did you already try `console.dir`?)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that the 'request' object you mean.
For most of js object, you can try:

```
console.dir(req, {depth: null, colors: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. A request object does not mean anything without the context/technology from which it results. I assume you are working with some Web/Rest framework. As for the "pretty" I assume you want to trim informations out of it to only display what you want in the terminal? In that case take a look at a logger middleware you could add such as [Morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan).